# Why do I get iOS linker errors with my static libraries?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, static-libraries, static-linking

I have a problem with linking my mixed language framework to a project.

1. I create a framework with Swift and Objective-C classes.
2. The main logic was stored in the Swift file. For example the class with a method that calls NSLog("Swift log was called").
3. Objective-C file has a class that has a method in which I create an instance of Swift class and call Swift-log method.
4. I link this framework with my Objective-C project, I can call all that I need in this project, but when I want to build this project I receive error `linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

   And warnings:

```
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftFoundation'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftDarwin'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftCoreFoundation'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftCore'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftCoreGraphics'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftObjectiveC'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftDispatch'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftSwiftOnoneSupport'
```

I also saw the solution with importing empty Swift-file, but it necessary to make a project without any trash.

Comment: @PhilippHolly I need a solution that will not include empty files.

Comment: I am sorry, I have not found any solution so far. let me know if you find something.

Comment: Hi Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 194):

1. Open ios/YourAppName.xcodeproj in Xcode
2. Right-click on Your App Name in the Project Navigator on the left, and click New File…
3. Create a single empty Swift file to the project (make sure that Your App Name target is selected when adding)
4. when Xcode asks, press Create Bridging Header and do not remove Swift file then.
   re-run your build.

This should fix the problem

Comment: What If I already have an existing bridging header and the problem persists? I'm running on `MacOS Mojave` and `XCode 11.3.1`

Comment: what if you're already have bridging file, can someone explain please

Comment: Xcode does not ask 'Create Bridging Header' , Xcode version: 12.4

Answer (score 99):

In my case it was a React-Native project after adding a Swift Pods library. Maybe just the step 2 can work:

1. Adding a new Swift file and a Brigde header:

1) `File -> New -> File`
[image: <code>File -> New -> File</code>]

2) Select `Swift File` [image: Select <code>Swift File</code>]

3) Confirm `Create Bridging Header` [image]

2. Go to `Build Settings` and set `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries` to `YES` [image: Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries]

Comment: Where will i put the file, under pods or the project?

Comment: @lutakyn I've put it in the project

Comment: Do not remove the dummy Swift file after the bridging file is created! Keep it or build fails

Comment: Step `Create Bridging Header` does not appear for me. It says `Save File` for me.

Comment: @dcangulo that steps appears only if your filename contains "bridging-header"

Answer (score 93):

Apparently for pure objective-c projects you will need to add this `$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift/$(PLATFORM_NAME)` to the **library search paths** of your target.  This worked for me when I was including a library written in swift to a project in objective-c

Comment: can you give us an example how we can added, as i am trying it but i don't really work for me , maybe aim placing it in a wrong place

Comment: @Nathan  How to set this in podspec, and not need add it manually?

Comment: This worked perfectly! For anyone wondering how exactly to do this; 
click your xcode project in the file explorer -> under `Targets` select your target -> select the `Build Settings` tab -> search for `Library Search Paths` and add `$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift/$(PLATFORM_NAME)` to the debug and release sections.

Comment: Unfortunately this trick seems to have stopped working when using Swift 5 with Xcode 10.2 - probably because there are now system-wide Swift libs with iOS 12.2.

Comment: For those who are new to Xcode make sure "All" is selected and is blue else you might not find Library search path

Comment: @megastep so how do fix it?

Comment: Try adding the following to your target's library search path: $(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME)

Comment: It compiles but then I got a crash at the launch of the application: "This copy of libswiftCore.dylib requires an OS version prior to 12.2.0".

If you want to solve it just add an empty swift file in the project, keep it forever and it will work. (The problem come from the fact that you are using both objective-c and swift code in your app)

Answer (score 26):

I have export my unity project. Earlier it was working just to add empty swift file with press create Bridging Header.

but recently i have updated my xCode to 12.3 and it stop working.

So, tried few other ways.

I have added `$(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/swift` to Build settings > Search paths > Library search paths.

but still it doesn't work. So, i have added in same path i.e Build settings > Search paths > Library search paths.

`$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift/$(PLATFORM_NAME)`

`$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME)`

Now it working perfect. Didn't get exact problem or solution but it works well with this way.

I just add these three in **Build settings > Search paths > Library search paths.**

1. $(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/swift
2. $(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift/$(PLATFORM_NAME)
3. $(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME)

Separately `TOOLCHAIN_DIR` directories doesn't work. If i add `$(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/swift` then only it work.

Comment: Tested in Xcode 12.5, `$(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/swift` needs to be the first

Comment: Thanks, it work for Xcode 13.1

Comment: Thanks,  it work for Xcode 13.2

Comment: Xcode 13.4.1 - it worked. Thanks!
I tried empty swift files, creating bridging headers manually, removing those lines - nothing worked.

The final solution included adding these 3 lines to the main target and *removing* those lines from another target which was a dependency to the main one

Answer (score 22):

For XCode 11 beta 4 **Library Search Paths** should be:

```
$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME)
```

Comment: I had to add this to each of my targets Library Search Paths property. Not just the main app. So, including my watch kit and Siri Intents targets.

Comment: Any targets with Swift code need to have the above mentioned path for XCode 11

Comment: Note if you have this in Xcode 12 still, it can f* your build.]\

Answer (score 15):

1. Right click project name and add a new swift file leave it as File.swift
2. it will ask you to create a new bridging header accept
3. Run the project again

Answer (score 13):

Try this workaround https://stackoverflow.com/a/50495316/1658268

Basically just add a dummy swift file in your project, and re-run your build.

Comment: You are the second who suggest this solution :). As I said in comments to description of my question, I need solution without empty Swift-files.

Answer (score 10):

If you have issue after update xCode to version 12 and errors

> Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftWebKit'

and two more.

Just addd `$(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/swift` to the **Build settings** > **Search paths** > **Library search paths**.

Hope its help :)

Comment: @SehiiVolynets, Please use italics (use `*` brackets) for pathways.

Comment: @maciejwww, what do you mean by "italics" and "asterisk brackets"? Which one should be used?

Comment: I mean formatting policy on StackOverflow. Using asterisk brackets formats text into italics: `*text*` --> *text*. For pathways in GUI, it's recommended to use *italics* or **bold** (double asteriks: `**text**`) font. However, in this case is better to use **bold** font than *italics*, I suppose. Now, my comment is no longer needed because @Niko have edited yours answer. Check it out and compare with your version. Short info about text fotmatting and example you can find [here](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1269857/2).

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks Xcode 12.5 iOS 14.5

Answer (score 9):

If your Xcode version is >=12.2

Go to

> BuildSettings -> Linking -> runpath search path

and add `/usr/lib/swift` as your 1st argument like this:

[image]

Comment: Can someone explain to me why the -1? Because I tried this and now I no longer need to constantly Clean => Rebuild whenever I change a single line. Note: I also needed to set "Enable Bitcode" as "No"

Comment: Worked fine for me, thanks a lot!!

Comment: When linking on command line, `-L /usr/lib/swift` worked great. It's much shorter than using the equivalent of `-L $(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/swift`. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Xcode 12.5, React Native.

Change: 'Library Search Paths' from Swift-5.0 to Swift-5.2[image]

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for this! Changing the Library Search Paths from swift-5.0 to swift-5.2 made my app finally build and run (it has nothing to do with watch apps or widgets).

Answer (score 6):

What worked for me in a React Native project is to move `$(inherited)` to the bottom of the list in Build Settings -> Library Search Paths

[image]

Comment: worked for me too. can you tell us why it works?

Comment: I have no idea, maybe an iOS dev can answer that.

Answer (score 3):

I've got the same errors when accidentally compiling a project with a Swift 5.0 Snapshot configured in the Xcode preferences » Components » Toolchain.

Comment: I've changed it on purpose...any way I can compile it on arm64 (works fine on simulator)?

Answer (score 2):

I am getting this error after installing Lottie-react-native?

The solution only works if it is caused by adding Lottie package.

This worked for me:

```
yarn add lottie-react-native
yarn add lottie-ios@3.2.3
```

And then must run:

`pod install` `or pod update`

I am using:

```
"lottie-ios": "3.2.3",
"lottie-react-native": "^5.0.1",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.67.3"
```

Answer (score 1):

XCode 11.3 beta, Swift 5.0

I just add my targets to the podfile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0' 
use_frameworks! 
inhibit_all_warnings!

def shared_pods
    # Pods for NamaIOS
    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'RxSwift'
end

target 'MyApp' do
  use_frameworks!

  shared_pods

end

target 'MyApp-Test' do
  use_frameworks!

  shared_pods

end

target 'MyApp-Development' do
  use_frameworks!

  shared_pods

end
```

Answer (score 1):

if you come from [lottie-react-native install instructions](https://github.com/react-native-community/lottie-react-native#installing-react-native--0600) just add `use_frameworks!` to podFile [#536 (comment)](https://github.com/react-native-community/lottie-react-native/issues/536#issuecomment-589564657)

Answer (score 1):

I am android programmer.
It took me a while understand what they were doing.
I have currently Xcode 13.2.1
And flutter 1 awful combination I know.
Please edit in other side xcode will take the enter like "I end"
I change  **Build settings > Search paths > Library search paths.**:
From:

> $(inherited) $(PROJECT_DIR)/Flutter

to:

> $(inherited) $(PROJECT_DIR)/Flutter $(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/swift
> $(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift/$(PLATFORM_NAME)
> $(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME)

Thats all,
I hope to help some folk.

Answer (score 0):

In case you encounter this error while using Xcode 11 beta 4 in combination with carthage see this workaround:

https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/2825

Basically it consists of creating a xcconfig with the fixes and inject these into each build.

Answer (score 0):

I only forget to Add the new Framework to my pod file :)

```
 target 'Data' do
inherit! :search_paths
 pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 5.2'
```

end

Answer (score 0):

for Xcode 12.2

Create an Empty Swift file using Xcode, such as named Void.swift, and every issue will be solved by Xcode automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue with our project and the issue was that there were orphaned references to lottie in our xcode project file.  Opening that in a text editor and removing them fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

What solved it for me when trying to integrate Lottie in my React Native project was to uninstall the lottie-ios and lottie-react-native modules with npm.

```
npm uninstall lottie-react-native lottie-ios
```

Make sure the files are unlinked as well

```
npx react-native unlink lottie-react-native lottie-ios
```

I also had the bridging-file in my project from previously trying that method without success so in order to replicate my process, follow the suggested answer and add that file to your project as well.

After these steps, I went ahead and deleted my Pods folder, cleaned my build from xcproject and xcworkspace (maybe one of these is enough).
After that I went ahead and installed the modules again

```
npm i --save lottie-react-native lottie-ios@3.1.3
```

(Make sure to check the current docks over at the lottie repo for the up-to-date versions.)

After you have reinstalled the modules, cd into your ios folder and run pod install.

Open up your xcworkspace in Xcode and run your project (make sure your build is clean).

This solved my issue.

Best of luck.

Comment: what lottie-react-native version you install

Comment: Hello @AftabAmin , thanks for the downvote .
If you read my post you'll see I follow the documentation over at the lottie RN docs: https://github.com/lottie-react-native/lottie-react-native
At the time of posting this a year ago I'm not too sure the version but give it a go with the latest stable release.
Good luck!

Comment: I have tried all the updated version but non is working. when I remove these libraries it works fine. tow months later my app was running. today I was updating my app and suddenly got this issue. also faced this a month ago but then I solved it.

Comment: @AftabAmin I see, that's too bad. let the devs over at lottie RN know about this by opening a through issue perhaps. Might help more people than yourself. Too bad I can't be of anymore help. Been a while since I worked with lottie.

Comment: @AftabAmin, how you fix it??