# ld: library not found for -lDoubleConversion React Native 0.59

Tags: ios, react-native

I have this error

```
❌  ld: library not found for -lDoubleConversion

❌  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening App.xcworkspace

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    Ld /Users/mohamedelmi/workspace/elmi/food-frontend/ios/build/App/Build/Intermediates.noindex/App.build/Release-iphonesimulator/App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/App normal x86_64
(1 failure)
```

here is what i did

1. I clean and rebuild still have the error
2. rm -f ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCach

Comment: did you fix this Hassan?

Comment: @Mohamed, did you ever fix this? Did the answer below work? I do not see it checked off.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, make sure that `Libraries -> React.xcodeproj -> ThirdParty -> double-conversion` exists and a static library is being produced from it, like this:

[image]

Then, if are you're using cocoapods, make sure to add `DoubleConversion` to your `Podfile`:

```rb
target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'React', :path => "../node_modules/react-native", :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'CxxBridge',
    'DevSupport',
    # the following ones are the ones taken from "Libraries" in Xcode:
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    'RCTBlob',
    'RCTGeolocation',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTVibration',
    'RCTWebSocket'
  ]
  pod 'yoga', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga"

  # Here it goes
  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec"

  pod 'glog', :podspec => "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec"
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec"
end
```

And finally, if none of this worked so far, there's a script you can manually run
in order to resolve React's third-party dependencies.

Just go to `node_modules/react-native` and type:

```sh
$ ./scripts/ios-install-third-party.sh
```

**Important**: Always run it inside `node_modules/react-native`. Because, as far as I know, the script uses relative paths in order to store third-party's source code and react native will always look for it at `node_modules/react-native/third-party`. So just make sure to run it in the right place.

**Note**: This script is, probably, already running as a build phase on your project.

Comment: I have the same issue with DoubleConversion. I did all steps as you told but build still failed with error: Library not found for -lDoubleConversion. Any ideas?

Comment: This answer does not take into account the case where the failure described occurs only in release builds, not debug builds.

Comment: am also facing the same issue when i select any iosdevice(arm64,armv).but when i select my device its working.any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the answers on [Why linker link static libraries with errors? iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52536380/why-linker-link-static-libraries-with-errors-ios) but nothing worked for me since I was combining the answers.

I got it to work by **ONLY** doing the "create new Swift-file"-trick. So remove everything, do a fresh install and only add a new Swift-file that will create the *Bridging Header* (dont delete the Swift-file).

Answer (score 0):

This is what finally worked for me. (Before proceeding, make sure `pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'` is included in your podfiles

```
1. cd ios
2. Delete Podfile.lock
3. pod deintegrate
4. pod install
5. cd ..
6. rm -rf node_modules && yarn
7. Add use_frameworks! to your Podfile
```

Run react-native-run-ios or Build with Xcode by opening the xcworkspace file in your ios directory.

Answer (score 0):

**This is what finally worked for me.**

pod deintegrate

pod install

Open project in X-Code

Remove Resources folder from left sidebar

Build your project from New Build System.