# NativeModules is {} on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

Following https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios, I'm unable to get NativeModules to contain anything. It's just an empty object (i.e. {}), but it should have the CalendarManager object and associated addEvent() method attached. This is true both for the simulator and my physical device. I was able to get an Android NativeModule working, so it appears to just be an iOS issue.

React Native version: 0.61.5

Podfile

```
platform :ios, '11.0'

require_relative '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/cocoapods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target 'native' do
  rnPrefix = "../node_modules/react-native"

  # React Native and its dependencies
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/"
  pod 'React-Core', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/"
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/React/CoreModules"
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS"
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/Libraries/NativeAnimation"
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/Libraries/Blob"
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/Libraries/Image"
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/Libraries/LinkingIOS"
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/Libraries/Network"
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/Libraries/Settings"
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/Libraries/Text"
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/Libraries/Vibration"
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/"
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/"
  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/ReactCommon/cxxreact"
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/ReactCommon/jsi"
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor"
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/ReactCommon/jsinspector"
  pod 'ReactCommon/jscallinvoker', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/ReactCommon"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/ReactCommon/yoga"
  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => "#{rnPrefix}/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec"
  pod 'glog', :podspec => "#{rnPrefix}/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec"
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => "#{rnPrefix}/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec"

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'

  # Other native modules

  # Automatically detect installed unimodules
  use_unimodules!

  # react-native-cli autolinking
  use_native_modules!

  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/59564933
  use_frameworks!

end
```

Native.js

```
import { NativeModules } from "react-native";
...
console.log(NativeModules); // {}
```

CalendarManager.h

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface CalendarManager : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>
@end
```

CalendarManager.m

```
#import "CalendarManager.h"
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@implementation CalendarManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(addEvent:(NSString *)name location:(NSString *)location)
{
  RCTLogInfo(@"Pretending to create an event %@ at %@", name, location);
}

@end
```

Comment: any solution???