# Library not found for -lDoubleConversion Build failed

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native

[image]

**ALREADY TRY THIS**

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562596/library-not-found-for-ldoubleconversion

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55239646/ld-library-not-found-for-ldoubleconversion-react-native-0-59

here is what i did

- I clean and rebuild
- rm -f ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cache
- also add remove flags from **Other Linker Flags**
- also try to add .a file in Link Binary With library under **build phase**

**Still Not get Success**

Comment: Have you tried to delete Podfile.lock and re-install it?

Comment: Yes but still getting errors.But after removing resource folder and upgrade to new build system Im able to build it successfully.

Thanks for your response.