# How to open a Xcode 11 Beta 4 project in Xcode 10?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9, xcode11

I worked on a project in Xcode 11 Beta 4 and then downgraded to Xcode 10 and can't open the project.

I want to submit my app to the app store, but I kept getting error messages in Xcode 11 beta 4. I'm a beginner and I know I tampered with the build settings trying to make it work. I deleted Xcode 11 and downloaded Xcode 10 to try and archive through that, but now I can't even open the project with Xcode 10.

I started the project on Xcode 9, I believe. I tried archiving, but there was an `"SDK Version Issue"`, something with the old iOS. So I updated my Mac's operating system, and replaced Xcode 9 with Xcode 11 beta. That came with many more errors trying to archive, and I changed architectures and proxies and all that. So I deleted Xcode 11 and tried Xcode 10 but I can't open the project.

It says:

> "cannot be opened because it is in a future Xcode project file format. Adjust the project format using a compatible version of Xcode to allow it to be opened by this version of Xcode."

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Too late but you should use source control.

Comment: Install Xcode 11 and open the project. Lower the project file format number. Now you can open it in Xcode 10.

Comment: Where do I go to lower the project file format number?

Comment: In the File inspector when you edit the project.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are probably getting a ton of Swift errors.  The release notes for beta 4 acknowledge this is an issue.

The official workaround is to a custom build setting with the name LD_VERIFY_BITCODE, and set it to NO.

Just remember to remove when issue is resolved!

[image]

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work (I'm now in Xcode 10 btw). I click add user setting, put in "LD_VERIFY_BITCODE", and type in NO in the other side. I'm getting the nonzero exit code error.

Comment: Never mind, I changed something else with the architectures and it finally uploaded! I've been at this for days so thank you.

Comment: Glad you got it going. is sucks to get delayed by this kind of stuff :)

Comment: @ben_fm Can you elaborate on what "changed something else with the architectures" means?

Comment: I’d like to hear this too. Still running into this in Sep 2020

Comment: However, my issue is with a specific third party framework. See this OSS repo: https://github.com/zaptrem/react-native-transcription

It integrates deepspeech_ios.framework (also open source) and works with both debug and release, but archiving fails unless this flag is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

If problem still persists for XCode 11 beta 4, then try setting "**Library Search Paths**" to :

```
$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME)
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57126566/5576675

Answer (score 0):

I update Xcode to 14.1, and fix this Hundreds of compile errors.
You can try to update newest xcode.