# Problem Could not find auto-linked framework 'FirebaseMessaging'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I have 6 error, and I can’t even imagine what it could be.

maybe someone met her.

Error screenshot
[image]

Comment: The libPlatform.a line looks suspicious - and could be related the Firebase libraries are partitioned in a strange way.

Comment: You can use the answer in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59355750/6736184

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the pods from terminal can solve your problem.
- Open terminal and go to the project directory and run `pod install` command.

Comment: Check your pod file it should have firebase pods defined as:-
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

Comment: And close the Xcode before installing the pods and then open the .xcworkspace file.