# Could not find or use auto-linked library '..." after installing react-native-fbsdk

Tags: react-native, fbsdk

I am trying to install react-native-fbsdk via npm, and whereas my build worked perfectly before, once I install the library and install pods, I get the following error:

```
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreFoundation'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCompatibility50'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftObjectiveC'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftFoundation'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftsimd'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftDarwin'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftUIKit'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCore'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftQuartzCore'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreGraphics'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftPhotos'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftSwiftOnoneSupport'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreImage'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCompatibilityDynamicReplacements'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftMetal'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftDispatch'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftAVFoundation'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreMedia'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreAudio'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreMIDI'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreLocation'
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "protocol descriptor for Foundation.CustomNSError", referenced from:
      protocol conformance descriptor for __C_Synthesized.related decl 'e' for FBSDKLoginError : Foundation.CustomNSError in __C_Synthesized in libFBSDKLoginKit.a(LoginManager.o)
  "method descriptor for static Foundation.CustomNSError.errorDomain.getter : Swift.String", referenced from:
      protocol conformance descriptor for __C_Synthesized.related decl 'e' for FBSDKLoginError : Foundation.CustomNSError in __C_Synthesized in libFBSDKLoginKit.a(LoginManager.o)
  "method descriptor for Foundation.CustomNSError.errorUserInfo.getter : [Swift.String : Any]", referenced from:
      protocol conformance descriptor for __C_Synthesized.related decl 'e' for FBSDKLoginError : Foundation.CustomNSError in __C_Synthesized in libFBSDKLoginKit.a(LoginManager.o)
  "method descriptor for Foundation.CustomNSError.errorCode.getter : Swift.Int", referenced from:
      protocol conformance descriptor for __C_Synthesized.related decl 'e' for FBSDKLoginError : Foundation.CustomNSError in __C_Synthesized in libFBSDKLoginKit.a(LoginManager.o)
  "base conformance descriptor for Foundation.CustomNSError: Swift.Error", referenced from:
      protocol conformance descriptor for __C_Synthesized.related decl 'e' for FBSDKLoginError : Foundation.CustomNSError in __C_Synthesized in libFBSDKLoginKit.a(LoginManager.o)
  "protocol descriptor for Foundation._ErrorCodeProtocol", referenced from:

... etc
```

I've searched everywhere for a solution to this problem and I am not seeing how to solve this library issue.

I am on React Native .60.5 - is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Which React-Native version does the FBSDK version you installed support? You may need to either downgrade FBSDK or upgrade RN.

Comment: It have same problem on [github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/755), but there are no answer now.

Comment: Temporarily downgrading to v1.1.2 of react-native-fbsdk and 5.8.0 of fbsdk has solved the issue

Answer (score 4):

To resolve this problem you just need to add **swift file** and ** "Create Bridging Header"** in your Xcode project.

- open Xcode and under you project select New file and select **swift file**
- now clean your build and make new build.

Or you can see bellow link to understand this so well

[Why linker link static libraries with errors? iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52536380/why-linker-link-static-libraries-with-errors-ios/53101587#53101587)

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by [adding a .swift file via xcode](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/755#issuecomment-653043458)

1. open XCode project
2. create new file, select swift file
3. confirm "Create Bridging Header"
4. clean
5. build

I tried a few combinations of these steps but found I needed **all** of them (ie. it must be done via xcode, you do need the bridging header, and you do need to clean the build folder).