# fatal error: module map /lottie-react-native/lottie_react_native.modulemap' not found

Tags: react-native, lottie

I am upgrading the react native version from 0.63.0 to 0.64.0 but I get this error when compiling? Do you know how to solve it?

fatal error: module map file '/Users/iteme/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/apparta-bdsropvgtdqyxfbzxyuwoltrneow/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lottie-react-native/lottie_react_native.modulemap' not found

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6pSX.png)

this is enviroment:
"lottie-ios": "^3.1.8",
"lottie-react-native": "^4.0.2",
cocapods: 1.11.2

tried this but it did not work:

1-. rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
2-. elimina Podfile.lock
3-. pod install

and

1. react-native link

and

npm uninstall lottie-ios npm install lottie-ios@3.1.8 cd ios pod install

Answer (score 6):

If you are using a Mac with the Silicon chip and met this error with the iOS simulators, try to add **arm64** to **Excluded Architectures** in Build Settings for both the **app project** and **pod project**, this works for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution. to would fix your problem. this issue is due to the static library. Here are some answers from stackoverflow and GitHub issues.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/56176956/9570734
- https://github.com/lottie-react-native/lottie-react-native/issues/513#issuecomment-512530064
- https://github.com/lottie-react-native/lottie-react-native/issues/513#issuecomment-521185372

Hope this will solve your issue

Comment: I get this error Debug-iphonesimulator/lottie-ios/Lottie.modulemap' not found
only in when my scheme is Debug but when I change it to release Build is successful. How can we fix it?

Answer (score -1):

I also faced the same error. I was working on Reanimated but didn't work for me but this way I was able to compile the project again.

```
cd ios

pod install
```

and rebuild project again.